# Sublime Latexing - Can't disable \tabularnewline key binding since latest update

Tags: sublimetext3

I use Sublime 3 and the Latexing Package (system, OSX).  Latexing comes with a nice set of keybindings.  One of these is that within an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment, the keys `shift + enter` will insert a new line with a `\item` on it.  Ever since the recent update of Sublime Test 3 a few days ago, this has stopped working.  Instead, the behavior is instead inserting a `\tabularnewline` regardless of whether I am in an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment.  It seems that this `\tabularnewline` keybinding is overriding the one to insert `\item`.  I never actually use the `\tabularnewline` binding and so decided to just disable it completely.

I tried copying over the complete contents of the "Default" Latexing keybindings to the "User" file and then removing the keybinding pertaining to this operation:

```
  {
    "keys": ["shift+enter"],
    "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\\tabularnewline\n"},
    "context": [
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex", "operator": "equal"}
    ]
  },
```

When that did not work, I also tried changing the keys that trigger it. That also did not work.  I find this all odd because:

- I've never had problems with modifying default keybindings before.
- This particular issue didn't occur until the update of ST3.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling latexing, to no avail.  I also use the packages latex-snippets and latex-cwl.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling each of those as well, in addition to disabling them so that I would only have latexing enabled at a given time, but that also did not resolve things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last Sublime Text update included a new LaTeX syntax with several changes. One change was that the scope of list environments changed from `meta.function.environment.list` to `meta.environment.list`, which requires an update of the keybindings.

To get the `shift+enter` behavior back just add this to your keymap:

```js
{
    "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\\item $0"},
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.list"},
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

The new syntax has a better granularity on the different list environments, such that you can even add `\item[]` in descriptions by adding this below the other one:

```js
{
    "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\\item[$1] $0"},
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.list.description"},
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```